# UISplitViewController - Show popover for master view on viewDidLoad

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, orientation, uisplitviewcontroller, uipopovercontroller

Is it possible to show master view in popover on viewDidLoad (when the view is in portrait orientation)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Solution 1:

```
[self.popoverButtonItem.target performSelector: self.popoverButtonItem.action withObject: self.popoverButtonItem];
```

Solution 2:

```
[self.popoverController presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:toolbarButtonItem permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:NO];
```

But the trick is when to use these statements. I had to use a flag for this purpose, in order to show the popover only once on startup, and only after i have a reference to my `popoverController` i.e. after split view delegate method calls.

Answer (score 0):

With iOS 8.0 the Splitviewcontroller supports a `preferredDisplayMode` which might be an elegant solution for this use case. From Apple Documentation:

```
UISplitViewControllerDisplayModePrimaryOverlay
The primary view controller is layered on top of the secondary view controller, leaving the secondary view controller partially vis{ible.

Available in iOS 8.0 and later.
```