# Split view MasterView not showing in a popup but sliding in

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, cocoa-touch, uisplitviewcontroller

I am attempting my first iPad app after many iPhone apps.
When I load up the template for Master-Detail Application for iPad, the MasterView list slides in from the left when you press the Bar Button ike this:

[image: slide view]

yet i've seen loads of images of this being a popup list like this:

[image: popup view]

What needs to be changed to make the standard template use the popup view?

Comment: You could use the solution explained in this link :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6854016/uisplitviewcontroller-show-popover-for-master-view-on-viewdidload

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The master view **used** to be a popup. It was changed (in iOS 5.1, I believe) to slide in from the left.  That's just how it works now.  To get a popup you'd have to "roll your own".

Comment: Ahhh, that explains it then. I think the popup looks so much nicer when in portrait, strange for them to change it. Do you know of any tutorials to change back to a popup?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know of anything specific to do that.

Answer (score 1):

From the Apple documentation:

```
UISplitViewControllerDisplayModePrimaryOverlay
The primary view controller is layered on top of the secondary view controller, leaving the secondary view controller partially visible.

Available in iOS 8.0 and later.
```

To get a popup you have to set the `preferredDisplayMode` property on your `UISplitViewController` to `UISplitViewControllerDisplayModePrimaryOverlay`.